# How to get data on clicking span

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

At page loads some datas are listing. My purpose is to delete each data from database when user click on cross span. I have added a cross button it's class name is "removefetchedData". At present my issue is when user clicks on cross, only one id is showing.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lr6a5d2v/17/)

**JS**

```
//fake data for this test
var response = {
    availableLanguage: [{
        id: "1",
        language_id: "English",
        title_en: "USEnglish"
    }, {
        id: "2",
        title_en: "Hindi"
    }, {
        id: "3",
        title_en: "Arabi"
    }

    ]
}


var responseDB = {
    selectLanguageRankingTagId: [{
        id: "1",
        user_id: "11",
        language_id: "English",
        ranking: "2",
        title_en: "English"
    }, {
        id: "2",
        user_id: "11",
        language_id: "German",
        ranking: "3",
        title_en: "German"
    }, {
        id: "3",
        user_id: "11",
        language_id: "French",
        ranking: "4",
        title_en: "French"
    }

    ]
}


var $languagemodal = $('#languagemodal'); // get the modal and the dialog div
var $dialog = $languagemodal.find('.modal-dialog');

//$languagemodal.modal({show: true}); // just to show the modal for the demo

// get languages
//$.get("/tag/language", function(response){
        var optionLang = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < response.availableLanguage.length; i++) {
            engLangID  = response.availableLanguage[i].id;
            engLang    = response.availableLanguage[i].title_en;
            optionLang += '<option value="'+engLangID+'" data-language="'+engLang+'">'+engLang+'</option>';
        }

// load the modal content div
$dialog.html('<div class="modal-content"><div class="modal-header "><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button><h4 class="modal-title">Edit Languages</h4></div><div class="modal-body"><div class="appendRow"></div></div><div class="modal-footer"><div class="row"><select class="form-control input-sm addMore"><option selected="selected">Add Language</option>' + optionLang + '</select></div><br><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button></div></div>');

// get the modal body we just added
var $modalBody = $dialog.find('.modal-body');

// loop over your data, you would have this in your $.get function 
var delID = 0;
$.each(responseDB.selectLanguageRankingTagId, function (i, item) {
    delID = item.id;
    // make the row
    var $newRow = $('<div class="row"><div class="col-md-8"><h4 style="background-color: lightgrey; border-radius: 10px; background-repeat: repeat; height: 30px; margin:5px 0px; padding:4px 5px;">' + item.title_en + '</h4></div><div class="col-md-3" style="padding:5px;"><select class="form-control input-sm" id="' + item.id + '" data-item="' + item + '"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option></select><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove removefetchedData" data-removefile=""></span></div></div>')
    // set the select value
    $newRow.find('select').val(item.ranking);
    // add the row to the modal body
    $modalBody.append($newRow);

});

//remove rank and language of users
                $( ".removefetchedData" ).click(function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    alert(delID);
                    /*$.post("/language/delete", {rateUserLangID: userLangDelID}, function(html){
                     //append css design
                     });*/
                });

$(".modal-dialog").on('change', ".addMore", function(){
            var selected = $( this ).find(':selected');
            language       = selected.data('language');
            languageID     = selected.val();
            $( ".appendRow" ).append('<div class="row"><div class="col-md-8"><h4 style="background-color: lightgrey; border-radius: 10px; background-repeat: repeat; height: 30px; margin:5px 0px; padding:4px 5px;">'+language+'</h4></div><div class="col-md-3" style="padding:5px;"><select class="form-control input-sm"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option></select><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove removefile" data-removefile=""></span></div></div>');
        });    

$('.modal-dialog').on('click', '.removefile', function() {
    $(this).closest('.row').remove();
});

 //});// get languages end
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="languagemodal">
  <div class="modal-dialog" style="margin: 54px 0px;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks like your alerting on the delID which would be the last value you set it to in the each.  If you want to provide some context you'll have to associate each id with its given removefetchedData element.  You could do this with a data-id="value" tag.  And then when you want to look it up you just do $(this).data('id').

Answer (score 0):

As you are not giving id to remove button you can do something like this :

```
$( ".removefetchedData" ).click(function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    alert($(this).parents('.row').find('.input-sm').attr('id'));
                });
```

jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Lr6a5d2v/18/

the above method works and gives you an `id` which you used to make `select box` so we can use that id send it to `php file` for further proccess.

and what other thing i can see is you are making the html of cross(remove button) within javascript so you can also do like give an data-id="" to the button and then inside javascript use that id:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove removefetchedData" data-removefile="" data-id="'+item.id+'"></span>
```

js

```
   $( ".removefetchedData" ).click(function(e){
                        e.preventDefault();
                        alert($(this).data('id'));
                    });
```

js fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Lr6a5d2v/19/